# Движение корабля в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как реализовать "вылет корабля" представленного ромбами из нижней части экрана браузера ?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    n = 20;
  var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.height = currentHeight;
  canvas.width = currentHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var i = 0;
  var w = currentHeight / 100,
    h = w;


  var centerX = 50 * w,
    centerY = 50 * h;

  var colorMainBg = "#000",
    colorArr = ["#00C77F", "#00916B", "#00FF8A", "#00C77F"];


  function createTriangle(horizontalShift, verticalShift, bgColor) {

    ctx.fillStyle = bgColor;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX, verticalShift);
    ctx.lineTo(horizontalShift, centerY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

  }

  function darkRombus() {
    ctx.lineWidth = '1';
    ctx.fillStyle = colorMainBg;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY - 8 * h);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + 5 * w, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY + 8 * h);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX - 5 * w, centerY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }



  var kx = 8,
    ky = 12; // 8

  function createRhombus() {
    createTriangle(centerX - kx * w, centerY - ky * w, colorArr[0]);
    createTriangle(centerX - kx * w, centerY + ky * w, colorArr[1]);
    createTriangle(centerX + kx * w, centerY - ky * w, colorArr[2]);
    createTriangle(centerX + kx * w, centerY + ky * w, colorArr[3]);
    darkRombus();

  }

  function animationRhombus() {

    // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var i = centerY * 2;

    while (i >= 0) {

      i = i - 100 * h;

      var t = i;

      ctx.translate(0, t);
      createRhombus();

      ctx.scale(0.7, 0.7);
      ctx.translate(centerX - (16.6 * w), centerY - (16 * h));
      createRhombus();


      ctx.translate(centerX - (74 * w), centerY - (50 * h));
      createRhombus();


      console.log(i);
      return i
    }

  }

  setInterval(animationRhombus, 10000 / 60);


}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Не получается правильно прописать функцию animationRhombus, (пробовал и через for но ничего не получается), необходимо что бы корабль из 3 ромбов вылетал из нижней части экрана, и останавливался в ctx.translate(0, 0); (в центре экрана), а не как сейчас, после чего setInterval переставал работать. Дальше, хочется анимировать что бы коэффициент ky плавно переходил из значения 12 в значение 8 (равнобедренные ромбы)
 Первая анимация должна заканчиваться так (скажем через 3сек)
[image: корабль вверх]
Вторая анимация с изменением ky должна закончиться так 
[image: корабль развернут]

Comment: добавил картинок, надеюсь так понятнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание на методы

```
ctx.save()
...
ctx.restore();
```

они сохраняют и восстанавливают значения контекста соответственно, так легче к началу нового кадра получить корректное состояние канвы, иначе Вы рисуете новый кадр поверх уже сдвинутого контекста с прошлой итерации, таким образом у Вас аккумулировались `translate` и `scale`...

```js
var currentHeight = canvas.height = canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = currentHeight / 100, h = w, centerX = 50 * w, centerY = 50 * h, 
  pos = 0, dr = 1, rot = 0;
var colorMainBg = "#000", colorArr = ["#00C77F", "#00916B", "#00FF8A", "#00C77F"];

function createTriangle(horizontalShift, verticalShift, bgColor) {
  ctx.fillStyle = bgColor;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
  ctx.lineTo(centerX, verticalShift);
  ctx.lineTo(horizontalShift, centerY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function darkRombus() {
  ctx.lineWidth = '1';
  ctx.fillStyle = colorMainBg;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY - 8 * h*dr);
  ctx.lineTo(centerX + 5 * w*dr, centerY);
  ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY + 8 * h*dr);
  ctx.lineTo(centerX - 5 * w*dr, centerY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

var kx = 8, ky = 12; // 8

function createRhombus() {
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY)
  ctx.rotate(rot*Math.PI/2);
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY)
  createTriangle(centerX - kx * w, centerY - ky * w, colorArr[0]);
  createTriangle(centerX - kx * w, centerY + ky * w, colorArr[1]);
  createTriangle(centerX + kx * w, centerY - ky * w, colorArr[2]);
  createTriangle(centerX + kx * w, centerY + ky * w, colorArr[3]);
  darkRombus();
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY)
  ctx.rotate(-rot*Math.PI/2);
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY)
}

function animationRhombus() {
  if (pos<currentHeight/2 + 50) 
    pos = pos + 3;
  else if (ky > 8)
    ky = Math.max(8, ky - 0.05);
  else if (dr > 0)
    dr = Math.max(0, dr - 0.01);
  else
    rot = Math.min(1, rot + 0.05);
  ctx.save()
  ctx.translate(0, currentHeight/2 + 60 -pos);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);
  ctx.translate(33*w, 65*h);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.translate(34*w, 0);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);
  ctx.translate(33*w, 65*h);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.translate(34*w, 0);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.translate(-102*w, 0);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.translate(34*w, 0);
  createRhombus();
  ctx.restore();
}

setInterval(animationRhombus, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Можете, ещё пояснить за ky = Math.max(8, ky - 0.05) не могу понять откуда берутся такие странные коэффициенты, и почему оно работает ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 читайте это как «на каждый кадр Вычитать из kY по 0.05 пока не станет 8»

Comment: Дошло, этот 0.05 был подобран методом подбора) Тогда ещё один вопрос, А если мне необходимо продолжить анимации из последнего ключевого кадра, как это сделать ? Предположим на 3-м этапе я хочу что б darkRombus плавно исчезал (суужаясь по вертикали и горизонтали), как вызвать функцию фидбека, которая отработает когда первых два этапа анимации закончат действие ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я сделаю пример, как доберусь до компа

Comment: @BlackStar1991 изменил ответ